# Android and FFmpeg. Video is very slow

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, decode

I have built ffmpeg library for my Android device from here: https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg. But some video files playing very very slow (i find out that very slow are playing videos which my Android device can play by itself). Here is build.sh script
https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg/blob/master/FFmpegLibrary/jni/build_android.sh

May be this is because of these lines:

```
--enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi \
--enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi \
--enable-hwaccel=h264_dxva2 \
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg4_vaapi \
```

As I have understood these lines are enabling hw acceleration (the author of that code says that this can raise some bugs). The basic idea of the player is to decode video and audio streams in native code, then render video frame into AndroidBitmap and render Audio into Android MediaPlayer. 
Does anyone know how to solve problem of slow video decoding (maybe decrease video frame resolution or something else?) I will be pleased for any help and ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Strange that `--enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi` is specified twice in a row, but I see that it's in the original build script that you linked to.

DXVA2 refers to [DirectX Video Acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX_Video_Acceleration), available on Windows desktop computers. So that won't help here. VAAPI refers to [Video Acceleration API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Acceleration_API). I was about to say that it targets only Unix desktops, but the Wikipedia page states that it can also target Android.

The likely reason that the decode is slow is that a software decode path is being taken. What type of video data are you decoding, and at what profile and resolution? Generally, it's best to leverage the Android media facilities, such as [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for playback, unless you're doing something special. You have probably already researched this option and perhaps you found that you can't obtain raw AndroidBitmaps (I am not too familiar with Android development).

I'm looking at the source for both FFmpeg's VAAPI interface and the VAAPI->Android code. If you have FFmpeg compiled for Android, how is it accessing VAAPI? Do you have VAAPI compiled for Android as well? I have a feeling that VAAPI is not a stock component of Android (but again, I'm not sure), so you may need to ensure that VAAPI is in place. Then, are you correctly asking FFmpeg to use VAAPI? I don't think FFmpeg will autodetect this.

Comment: Mike I am very glad for your answer.  I dont know the original video resolution, (but from the log level I find out that it is  look like 1000 and something x1000  and something). Video formats are flv and wmv with H.264 CODEC. Sorry  for my English :-)